# The Gauge needle is always started from 0 when it's value is updated | HighCharts with Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, highcharts

I am working on Angular 7 project where I need to implement highchart gauge. The implemented gauge have 3 needles. One of the needles is getting it' value updated every 1 minute. The problem is that the needle always start again from 0.

I tried to set the `animation:false` this works but I want the needle to animate as it looks much better.

```
public gauge_options: any = {
      chart: {      
         type: 'gauge',
      },
      series: [{
         animation: false,
         name: 'max',
         data: [128],
         dial: {
           backgroundColor: 'red'
         }
       }, {
         animation: false,
         name: 'KW',
         data: [105],
         dial: {
           backgroundColor: 'black'
         }
       }, {
         animation: false,
         name: 'min',
         data: [21],
         dial: {
           backgroundColor: 'green'
         }
      }]
   }
```

and on API response:

```
 this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => this.getApiResponse(apiLink).then(
      data => {
    this.gauge_options.series[1].data[0]=data[0]; // data[0] is a number between 0 and 160
    Highcharts.chart('container', this.gauge_options);
   },
  error => {
    console.log('Something went wrong.');
  })
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue and to me everything works as it should be - please take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fbvmj1qt/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follow:

```
   this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => this.getApiResponse(apiLink).then(
      data => {

        Highcharts.chart(this.gauge_container_id,this.gauge_options,function (chart) {
          chart.series[1].points[0].update(data[0]);
       });
   },
  error => {
    console.log('Something went wrong.');
  })
```